AWS Lambda - FFmpeg to extract frames doesn't write anything
I have a lambda with a ffmpeg layer on it.
The command i want to use is basically
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -qscale:v 2 -vf fps=8 '%04d.jpg'

so it has an input file, and creates 8 frames per second in the same folder
This code seems to do everything except writing the files, what am I missing ?
import ...
SIGNED_URL_TIMEOUT = 60
FPS_SAMPLES = 8

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # Set up logging.
    logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

    s3_client = boto3.client('s3')

    s3_source_bucket = event['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name']
    s3_source_key = event['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['key']

    s3_source_basename = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(s3_source_key))[0]

    logger.info( "bucket: %s, key: %s, basename: %s",s3_source_bucket, s3_source_key, s3_source_basename)

    s3_source_signed_url = s3_client.generate_presigned_url('get_object',
    Params={'Bucket': s3_source_bucket, 'Key': s3_source_key},
    ExpiresIn=SIGNED_URL_TIMEOUT)

    with tempfile.TemporaryDirectory() as tmpdir:
        os.chdir(tmpdir) # change the current folder to that one (current one is in     os.getcwd())
        cwd = os.getcwd()
        ffmpeg_cmd = "/opt/bin/ffmpeg -i \"" + s3_source_signed_url + "\" -qscale:v 2 -vf fps="+str(FPS_SAMPLES)+" "+ cwd + "/'%04d.jpg'"
    print("COMMAND: "+ffmpeg_cmd)
    
        command1 = shlex.split(ffmpeg_cmd)
        p1 = subprocess.run(command1, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

        # List all files and directories in the current directory
        contents = os.listdir(cwd)
    
        # Print the contents
        print(f"Contents of {cwd}:")
        for item in contents:
            print(item) # <--- NOthing here...

   
return {
    'statusCode': 200,
    'body': json.dumps("bucket: %s, key: %s, basename: %s" % (s3_source_bucket, s3_source_key, s3_source_basename))
}


This might be better than calling a subprocess: How to Use FFMpeg in Python (with Examples) - Bannerbear

A long standing issue/limitation with ffmpeg means the static build doesn't support DNS requests.  In other words, you'll need some solution to passing it a normal URL, like downloading the content in Python to a local temp file first and passing that local temp file as input.

are you sure about these ? this code almost literally comes from aws blog:
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/media/processing-user-generated-content-using-aws-lambda-and-ffmpeg/

Yes, I'm sure.  That blog post links to a website which includes this warning in the readme: "A limitation of statically linking glibc is the loss of DNS resolution".  That blog post has caused no end of confusion over the years, yet it remains for some reason.

@AnonCoward - You made my day buddy! I was struggling with this, did not know this is a limitation.

AWS Lambda functions can only write to the /tmp/ directory, so make sure the temporary directory is being created there.
It might also be better to have the Lambda function download the input file to /tmp/ and then pass that file to ffmpeg. This way, you can better diagnose what might be happening.
Also, please note that the Lambda environment might be re-used, so it is generally a good idea to delete newly-created files before exiting the Lambda function otherwise the available disk space (512MB by default) might be filled by subsequent executions.

temporaryDirectory should be the function to use OS tmp dir and create a new folder inside it; in this code an example is /tmp/tmpuojcbc1m , so it is working in /tmp ...
Anyway, i tried downloading instead of accessing it remotely and this worked. So the issue was that it wasn't fetching the video from the presigned url.
The odd thing is that this code came from aws blog so i don't know...
I found really helpfuly your last info about deleting the file, if you could consider removing the tmp part from the answer (that was actually correct, so it's misleading) i'll approve the answer ty

Glad you got it working!

As you mentioned, you're following along with the example code from AWS seen in their blog.
This is problematic.  This worked a few versions of FFMpeg ago due to a quirk with how it was built back then.  For quite a while, the static builds of FFMpeg have included this warning:

A limitation of statically linking glibc is the loss of DNS resolution

This means you can no longer use FFMpeg in any scenario where it will make a DNS query when run on Lambda with a static build, such as passing it a presigned URL.  One way to work around this is to use Python to download the content, then pass it to FFMpeg to work on.
There is another more direct way:  Perform the DNS query manually, modify the URL, and pass the modified URL to FFMpeg along with some HTTP headers to work around the fact the URL has been changed.  This will prevent the need for the local storage for the original content (and indeed, can be used to stream content back to S3 directly depending on the output format).  Here's an example of that:
import boto3, os, stat, subprocess
from urllib.parse import urlparse
from socket import gethostbyname

s3 = boto3.client('s3')
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # TODO: Get a copy of ffmpeg from S3 for this example
    #       It probably makes more sense to include it in the Lambda archive
    if not os.path.isfile('/tmp/ffmpeg'):
        s3.download_file('example-bucket', 'temp/ffmpeg', '/tmp/ffmpeg')
        st = os.stat('/tmp/ffmpeg')
        os.chmod('/tmp/ffmpeg', st.st_mode | stat.S_IEXEC)

    # Generate a presigned URL for an artifact in S3
    url = s3.generate_presigned_url(
        'get_object', 
        Params={'Bucket': 'example-bucket', 'Key': 'temp/example.mp3'}, 
        ExpiresIn=300,
    )

    # Pull the hostname out of the URL, and replace it with a IP address
    parsed = urlparse(url)
    hostname = parsed.hostname
    parsed = parsed._replace(netloc=gethostbyname(hostname))
    url = parsed.geturl()

    # Call FFMpeg with the target URL, along with the hostname so the webserver 
    # will properly parse the request. For this example, just transcode the MP3 
    # to a constant bitrate, the exact call you want to make to FFMpeg will 
    # no doubt differ
    subprocess.check_call([
        '/tmp/ffmpeg', 
        '-headers', f"Host: {hostname}",
        '-i', url, 
        "-ar", "44100", "-ac", "1", "-b:a", "64k",
        "/tmp/output.mp3",
    ])

    # For this example, just upload the object back to S3
    s3.upload_file('/tmp/output.mp3', 'example-bucket', 'temp/output.mp3')

    # TODO: Clean up /tmp when complete

    return {'statusCode': 200, 'body': "OK"}


I want to add a comment for future readers (and future me), this is a very important part of the answer; read this also to understand what's happening
